# SSRS auto refresh (AutoRefresh) only partially works on particular clients

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We've been successfully using SSRS auto refresh (SQL Server 2008R2) on a variety of clients over the years and never had any problems. Various combinations of Chrome and IE on various OSs (windows XP, 7 and 10) have all been fine. We've just deployed a new report to run in full screen mode on TV screens, and it seems to be PARTIALLY refreshing. The Globals!ExecutionTime displays accurately, but new rows (INSERTs in the source data) in the report's tablix do not show up until the report is manually refreshed. Even more oddly, UPDATEs to the source data seem to make it through the auto refresh process. The problem only seems to occur on these particular clients.

We've set up a report history to help monitor this problem, and it works as expected. In fact it highlights the inconsistency, where newer information is captured in snapshots that were run earlier that the screen autorefresh.

The report execution logs are recording exactly the executions we'd expect to see. The data is just not making it onto the screen.

The report's processing options are:

- Always run this report with the most recent data,
- Do not cache temporary copies of this report
  Any suggestions greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Maybe something in here could help. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9bc13904-a727-4786-9a11-693570f5f8d4/diable-the-cache-for-all-reports-in-ssrs-2008?forum=sqlreportingservices .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we eventually resolved it. The problem turned out to be not exactly as described above. It seems to have been due to unusual combination of several cascading parameters, and a rapidly changing underlying dataset. What would happen, is that:

1. The SQL behind the cascading parameters would be executed on autorefresh in order to populate each parameter's default values.
2. During or shortly after this, the source data would change.
3. Next the final dataset SQL would be executed using the now out-of-date parameter values, and bring back the wrong results.

The solution was to remove four of the five cascading parameters from the report (and the underlying stored procedure). The stored procedure had initially been intended to be widely used and that was the reason for needing all the parameters. Turns out though that it was only used by the report, so as luck would have it we were able to simplify the process.